# Encoding gives "'ascii' codec can't encode character … ordinal not in range(128)"

Tags: python, django, unicode, character-encoding

I am working through the Django RSS reader project [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/djangoproject.com/django_website/apps/aggregator/bin/update_feeds.py).

The RSS feed will read something like "OKLAHOMA CITY (AP) — James Harden let".  The RSS feed's encoding reads encoding="UTF-8" so I believe I am passing utf-8 to markdown in the code snippet below.  The em dash is where it chokes.

I get the Django error of "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 109: ordinal not in range(128)" which is an UnicodeEncodeError. In the variables being passed I see "OKLAHOMA CITY (AP) \u2014 James Harden".  The code line that is not working is:

```
content = content.encode(parsed_feed.encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
```

I am using markdown 2.0, django 1.1, and python 2.4.

What is the magic sequence of encoding and decoding that I need to do to make this work?

---

(In response to Prometheus' request.  I agree the formatting helps)

So in views I add a smart_unicode line above the parsed_feed encoding line...

```
content = smart_unicode(content, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict')
content = content = content.encode(parsed_feed.encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
```

This pushes the problem to my models.py for me where I have

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False): 
     if self.excerpt: 
         self.excerpt_html = markdown(self.excerpt) 
         # super save after this
```

If I change the save method to have...

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False): 
     if self.excerpt: 
         encoded_excerpt_html = (self.excerpt).encode('utf-8') 
         self.excerpt_html = markdown(encoded_excerpt_html)
```

I get the error **"'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 141: ordinal not in range(128)"** because now it reads "\xe2\x80\x94" where the em dash was

Comment: could you please post the traceback as-is?

Comment: Basically, what's the value of `parsed_feed.encoding`? Is it 'ascii', per chance? (that would explain both your errors).

Answer (score 14):

If the data that you are receiving is, in fact, encoded in UTF-8, then it should be a sequence of bytes -- a Python 'str' object, in Python 2.X

You can verify this with an assertion:

```
assert isinstance(content, str)
```

Once you know that that's true, you can move to the actual encoding. Python doesn't do transcoding -- directly from UTF-8 to ASCII, for instance. You need to first turn your sequence of bytes into a Unicode string, by decoding it:

```
unicode_content = content.decode('utf-8')
```

(If you can trust parsed_feed.encoding, then use that instead of the literal 'utf-8'. Either way, be prepared for errors.)

You can then take that string, and encode it in ASCII, substituting high characters with their XML entity equivalents:

```
xml_content = unicode_content.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

The full method, then, would look somthing like this:

```
try:
    content = content.decode(parsed_feed.encoding).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # Couldn't decode the incoming string -- possibly not encoded in utf-8
    # Do something here to report the error
```

Answer (score 4):

[Django provides a couple of useful functions for converting back and forth between Unicode and bytestrings:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions)

> from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode, smart_str

Comment: Using...
content = smart_unicode(content, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict')
    content = content = content.encode(parsed_feed.encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")

pushes the problem to my models.py for me where I have
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        if self.excerpt:
            self.excerpt_html = markdown(self.excerpt)
        # super save after this

If I change the save method to have
       encoded_excerpt_html = (self.excerpt).encode('utf-8')
       self.excerpt_html = markdown(encoded_excerpt_html)

Comment: Part 2: I get the error "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 141: ordinal not in range(128)" because now it reads "\xe2\x80\x94" where the em dash was.

Comment: Could you please amend your original post with the above? It's very difficult to read without proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error during a write of a file name with zip file. The following failed

```
ZipFile.write(root+'/%s'%file, newRoot + '/%s'%file)
```

and the following worked

```
ZipFile.write(str(root+'/%s'%file), str(newRoot + '/%s'%file))
```

Comment: Calling `str()` on a unicode value with non-ASCII characters would result in the exact same error the OP is seeing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Hi, that is a very important point that you make. I can find no reference to what `str()` is actually doing in [the fine manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) however I attribute that to me being a Python noob more than a fault of the manual. Where is this documented, what exactly is `str()` doing to the argument, and what exactly does `str()` return? Thanks!

Comment: `str()` returns a *byte string*; characters with values between 0 and 255, with 0-127 usually interpreted and displayed as ASCII characters. A `unicode()` value, on the other hand, can represent any codepoint in the Unicode standard, between 0 and 1114111. So using `str(unicodevalue)` to turn unicode into a byte string is going to involve *some* transformation.

Comment: The `unicode` type is implemented in C, but it provides the C API equivalent of the `__str__` hook to make that transformation; the [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ca8e86711403/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l7553) calls [`PyUnicode_AsEncodedString()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ca8e86711403/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l1291), and that function uses `PyUnicode_GetDefaultEncoding()`; guess what that function does. :-)

Comment: Since you cannot pass in an encoding to `str()`, Python does not have a choice but to use the default encoding. So it is always **much better** to explicitly encode to a byte string, when you need the latter. Don't use `str(unicodevalue)`; it rarely is a good idea.