# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I am attempting to work with a very large dataset that has some non-standard characters in it. I need to use unicode, as per the job specs, but I am baffled. (And quite possibly doing it all wrong.)

I open the CSV using:

```
 15     ncesReader = csv.reader(open('geocoded_output.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
```

Then, I attempt to encode it with:

```
name=school_name.encode('utf-8'), street=row[9].encode('utf-8'), city=row[10].encode('utf-8'), state=row[11].encode('utf-8'), zip5=row[12], zip4=row[13],county=row[25].encode('utf-8'), lat=row[22], lng=row[23])
```

I'm encoding everything except the lat and lng because those need to be sent out to an API. When I run the program to parse the dataset into what I can use, I get the following Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "push_into_db.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "push_into_db.py", line 74, in main
    district_map = buildDistrictSchoolMap()
  File "push_into_db.py", line 32, in buildDistrictSchoolMap
    county=row[25].encode('utf-8'), lat=row[22], lng=row[23])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think I should tell you that I'm using python 2.7.2, and this is part of an app build on django 1.4. I've read several posts on this topic, but none of them seem to directly apply. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

You might also want to know that some of the non-standard characters causing the issue are Ñ and possibly É.

Comment: What is your original file encoding? I think you should decode it according to the original encoding and then convert to utf 8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding gives "'ascii' codec can't encode character … ordinal not in range(128)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513027/encoding-gives-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-ordinal-not-in-range128) [Ed.: and of approximately a zillion others, too, I'm sure.]

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Unicode is not equal to UTF-8. The latter is just an *encoding* for the former.

You are doing it the wrong way around. You are *reading* UTF-8-*encoded* data, so you have to *decode* the UTF-8-encoded String into a unicode string.

So just replace `.encode` with `.decode`, and it should work (if your .csv is UTF-8-encoded).

Nothing to be ashamed of, though. I bet 3 in 5 programmers had trouble at first understanding this, if not more ;)

Update:
If your input data is *not* UTF-8 encoded, then you have to `.decode()` with the appropriate encoding, of course. If nothing is given, python assumes ASCII, which obviously fails on non-ASCII-characters.

Comment: The reason for the error being that Python is trying to automatically decode it from the default encoding, ASCII, so that it can then encode it as he specified, to UTF-8. Since the data isn't valid ASCII, it doesn't work.

Comment: sure, but if it's UTF8-*encoded* data (as I guess), then `.decode('utf-8')` should do the trick, nor?

Comment: Sure, you're probably right. I was just explaining why you get that specific error in this situation.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. So it turns out that it was .decode('latin-1') -- this makes sense because it was Ñ that was giving me the problem. Again! Thank you!

Comment: Your solution works for some cases, but in case if I use this then I get another error
**'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)**

Comment: This is not the case always. The 2nd answer worked for me

Answer (score 100):

Just add this lines to your code:

1.Python2

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

2.Python3

```
import sys
from importlib import reload
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

does not seem to work in Python 3

Comment: It works for my Python 2.7, note, reload(sys) is needed, otherwise, setdefaultencoding would not be accessible.

Comment: That was the only thing that made it work for me out of many SO questions. Thanks so much!

Comment: name 'reload' is not defined

Comment: W00t for proselint/tools.py as well.

Comment: @Davide - from importlib import reload

Comment: For python3, see the @Skrmnghrd answer

Answer (score 47):

for Python 3 users. you can do

```
with open(csv_name_here, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    #some codes
```

it works  with flask too :)

Answer (score 11):

The main reason for the error is that the default encoding assumed by python is ASCII. 
Hence, if the string data to be encoded by `encode('utf8')` contains character that is outside of ASCII range e.g. for a string like 'hgvcj터파크387', python would throw error because the string is not in the expected encoding format.

If you are using python version earlier than version 3.5, a reliable fix would be to set the default encoding assumed by python to `utf8`:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
name = school_name.encode('utf8')
```

This way python would be able to anticipate characters within a string that fall outside of ASCII range.

However, if you are using python version 3.5 or above, reload() function is not available, so you would have to fix it using decode e.g.

```
name = school_name.decode('utf8').encode('utf8')
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and mine

Comment: More detailed. People often find causal details helpful. And your code works btw, no derogation intended.

Comment: reload is available in Python 3 you would just have to import it. from imp import reload

Comment: @Meow but there is no sys.setdefaultencoding in Python 3.
So in context of compatibility py2\py3 some check will do, sys.getdefaultencoding() maybe. Would appreciate a piece of advice about that matter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127513/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-setdefaultencoding

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3 users:

changing the encoding from 'ascii' to 'latin1' works.

Also, you can try finding the encoding automatically by reading the top 10000 bytes using the below snippet:

```
import chardet  
with open("dataset_path", 'rb') as rawdata:  
            result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))  
print(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

Check which locale you're using with the [`locale`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locale) command. If it's not `en_US.UTF-8`, [change it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue) like this:

```bash
sudo apt install locales 
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8    
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

If you don't have permission to do that you can run all your Python code [like this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING):

```bash
PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8" python3 ./path/to/your/script.py
```

or run this command before running your Python code

```bash
export PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"
```

to set it in the shell you run that in.

---

In my case, I was using `POSIX`, the default Ubuntu locale instead of `en_US.UTF-8`, so I saw this output:

```bash
$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

which caused Python to open files as ASCII instead of UTF-8.

You can check which locale Python is using like this:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

[`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) is the function [called by `open()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) when you don't provide an encoding. The output should be `'UTF-8'`, but in my case it was `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'`, some [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743106/whats-ansi-x3-4-1968-encoding) of ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

if you get this issue while running certbot while creating or renewing certificate, Please use the following method

`grep -r -P '[^\x00-\x7f]' /etc/apache2 /etc/letsencrypt /etc/nginx`

That command found the offending character "´" in one .conf file in the comment. After removing it (you can edit comments as you wish) and reloading nginx, everything worked again.

Source :https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5236

Answer (score 1):

Or when you deal with text in Python if it is a Unicode text, make a note it is Unicode.

Set `text=u'unicode text'` instead just `text='unicode text'`.

This worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with this issue inside of a Docker container.
It might be the case (as it was for me) that you only need to generate the locale and do nothing more:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

In some case that was sufficient for me because locales was already installed and configured. If you have to install locales and configure it, add the following part to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt update && apt install locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo 'LANG="en_US.UTF-8"'>/etc/default/locale && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

I tested it like this:

```
cat <<EOF > /tmp/test.txt
++*=|@#|¼üöäàéàè!´]]¬|¢|¢¬|{ł|¼½{}}
EOF

python3
import pathlib; pathlib.Path("/tmp/test.txt").read_text()
```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu recommends doing it this way: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8` and then `ENV LANG en_US.utf8`. Alternatively it says you can probably get away with just doing `ENV LANG C.UTF-8` (see the "Locales" section)

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this problem in a docker container. Maybe you need to configure locale.

```
apt-get install locales
dpkg-reconfigure locales # select 146(en_US.UTF-8)
echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this issue while using Pickle for unloading.
Try,

```
data = pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score -2):

open with encoding UTF 16 because of lat and long.

```
with open(csv_name_here, 'r', encoding="utf-16") as f:
```

Answer (score -2):

It does work by just taking the argument 'rb' read binary instead of 'r' read