# requests package with accented characters URLs produces UnicodeDecodeError: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have the following url link which has accented charaters:

[https://www.janes.com/...tamandaré](https://www.janes.com/...tamandar%C3%A9)... etc.

When I try to request the link, I get the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position
>   89: invalid continuation byte

This is my code:

```
import requests

def request_site(url):
    return requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0)'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.janes.com/article/87665/laad-2019-united-kingdom-s-sea-signs-mou-with-brazilian-siatt-for-tamandaré-class-corvette-torpedo-tubes'
    print(request_site(url))
```

The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/OneDrive/PhD/Web Crawler/playground.py", line 104, in <module>
    print(request_site(url))
  File "D:/OneDrive/PhD/Web Crawler/playground.py", line 73, in request_site
    return requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0)'})
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 149, in resolve_redirects
    url = self.get_redirect_target(resp)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 115, in get_redirect_target
    return to_native_string(location, 'utf8')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 25, in to_native_string
    out = string.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 89: invalid continuation byte
```

I found many questions (like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127513/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-setdefaultencoding)) that are similar, but non of them propose a solution for the same problem, as well as, all of the previous solutions are for python2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Comment: @ggorlen, plz check the question  .. they are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick encode is needed, but you'll need to drop the `http://` from `url` as it'll encode that as well:

```
import requests

def request_site(url):
    return requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0)'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'www.janes.com/article/87665/laad-2019-united-kingdom-s-sea-signs-mou-with-brazilian-siatt-for-tamandaré-class-corvette-torpedo-tubes'
    url_encode = 'http://' + urllib.parse.quote(url.encode('latin-1'))
    print(request_site(url_encode))
```

Comment: I got error from another site: https://velká-bíteš-takes-aim-at-indian-requirements-with-pbs-tj150-uav-engine, is there a more universal encoding to handle other kind of chars?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I’ll have to look at this one. I’ll get back to you.