# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my python env, `help()` return my python version is 2.7.

Then, I enter:

```
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

and it return this error: `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'"`

But my python version is 2.7.

Anyone? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127513/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-setdefaultencoding

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at documentation:

- [sys.setdefaultencoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding): "... Once used by the `site` module, it is removed from the `sys` module’s namespace."
- [site module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site): "**This module is automatically imported during initialization**. The automatic import can be suppressed using the interpreter’s `-S` option."