# Python gives UnicodeEncodeError reading xlsx

Tags: python, xlsx

When running this Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import unicodedata
import codecs

DataFile=pd.read_excel('indata.xlsx')#,dtype={'text': unicode})

for Rownumber in range (0,7):# 2? til 23761?
 print('rownumber: ', Rownumber)
 ColumnF=str((DataFile.iloc[Rownumber,5]))
 print('ColumnF: ', ColumnF)        
print('EOF')
```

I get the following error:

```
('rownumber: ', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 13, in <module>
    ColumnF=str((DataFile.iloc[Rownumber,5]))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe6' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

any idea how to make Python read xlsx containing non-ascii utf8 caharacters in xlsx?

Comment: add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406135/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xd1-in-position-2-ordinal/40346898#40346898

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the excel with an encoding:

**EX**:

```
DataFile=pd.read_excel('indata.xlsx', encoding = 'utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I got the same error as above.