# What's "ANSI_X3.4-1968" encoding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding, python-unicode

See following output on my system:

```
[STEP 101] # python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
[STEP 102] #
[STEP 103] # locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
[STEP 104] #
```

Googled but found very little info about it. Even Python's *The Python Library Reference (v3.5.2)* does not mention it. Any international standard defines it?

---

(Copied the authoritative ref from the accepted answer's comment: [Character Sets](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml))

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is another name for `USAS X3.4-1968`, a revision of `ASCII` that is distinguished by being:

- the first revision to allow a linefeed (`LF`) to occur on its own (i.e. not preceded by or followed by a carriage return (`CR`)).
- the revision that introduced the common name of `(US-)ASCII`.

This is basically `ASCII` as we think of it, although there were two minor revisions that followed it.

Comment: is `ANSI_X3.4-1968` an official name? or only in Python?

Comment: Yes it is an official name, the name has nothing to do with python see eg https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

Comment: also wondering why python uses this name but does not mention it in the doc. it only mentions `ascii` and `us-ascii`. this introduces unnecessary confusions.

Comment: @pynexj I was curious as well so I dug into the implementation -- see my answer below :)

Answer (score 9):

If you're curious where it comes from in ***c***python, the value is computed from the locale module using `langinfo`.

Here's a tiny C program which demonstrates how the `_locale` module determines this information:

```
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("%s\n", nl_langinfo(CODESET));
    return 0;
}
```

And some sample output:

```
$ LANG= ./a.out 
ANSI_X3.4-1968
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ./a.out 
UTF-8
```

python normalizes the ansi name to `ascii` (or `US-ASCII`)