# Encoding utf-8 from html form

Tags: python, django, utf-8, character-encoding

I've a Python/Django program which is currently running with some Greek characters.  I'm getting a problem with the following error: 
    `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)`

On this line of code

```
if l.answer == str(request.POST.get('resp_162')).encode('utf-8'):
```

The input is Μεξικό.  It clearly doesn't like the accented o.

I've read the documentation but I really don't get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding gives "'ascii' codec can't encode character … ordinal not in range(128)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513027/encoding-gives-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-ordinal-not-in-range128)

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to a bytestring instead of keeping it as text?

Comment: I've tried with and without the '.encode('utf-8') and get the same error

Comment: But *why* are you converting it to str at all? Why not just `if l.answer == request.POST.get('resp_162'))`?

Comment: Because today I'm being an idiot - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.POST.get('resp_162')` will return a `unicode` object (unicode string) - or `None` but well, that's another problem. There are two ways you can convert it to a `str` object (byte string): by passing it to `str` - ie `str(request.POST.get('resp_162'))` - *or* by encoding it to a byte string codec using `unicode.encode(...)`, ie `request.POST.get('resp_162').encode("utf-8")`. The first solution will use the 'ascii' codec, the second will use the codec you ask for.

Since you're *first* passing your `unicode` string to `str` and it contains non-ascii characters you get a `UnicodeEncodeError` at this point. IOW : just use the second solution and you won't have an error.

This being said : internally, Django only uses unicode strings (for what you get from your models, forms, request etc), and the only sane approach is to stick to unicode strings everywhere (decode the byte strings at system input and encode them to the desired encoding at system output). I don't know what `l.answer` is in your snippet but if 'l' (very bad naming choice FWIW) is a model instance and `.answer` a text field, it already is a `unicode` string so you really shouldn't try to make it a byte string.